# RoR form: adding text behind input-field

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

I am currently working on a registration form. Users should only register with an email-adress belonging to a specific domain (e.g. "@example.com"). I want to add this domain as a text behind the email-input-field to make it clear for the users what to enter. Unfortunately it seems impossible to write something behind an input-field as rails automatically does a line break.
This is the relevant part of the form:

```
<%= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>
    <div class="field">
        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.text_field :email, autofocus: true %>[@example.com]
    </div>
   
    <div class="actions">
        <%= f.submit "register", class: "button" %>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

The result should look like `[         ] @example.com`
Also I need the email-adress to be an actual email-adress. Therefore I also need to manipulate the input e.g. "john" to "john@example.com" before saving the user to the database.

How can I achieve these two things?

Comment: For the layout question, check/add the CSS for ``.field``. By default the ``text_field`` helper sets ``display: inline-block``, which should give you the layout you want. I suspect your CSS on the parent ``<div>`` is overriding that.

Comment: thanks. It seems like foundation was overwriting that. Adding `display: inline-block !important` to the header allowed multiple input-fields to be positioned in the same line. Unfortunately text (as plain HTML, and as label) is still moved to the next line.

Answer (score 0):

The strict answer to your question is that in your controller action you are free to manipulate or set attributes on an instance before you save it.

```rb
def create
 @foo = Foo.new(foo_params)
 @foo.email = mangle_email(@foo.email)
 if @foo.save
   ... # normal stuff
 end
end
```

In your particular case, you should consider the various input scenarios (e.g., user adds the `@domain` on their own, etc.), since there are lots of cases where just appending something to the end of the user input is probably not what you're after.

Comment: thanks. Is there a difference between doing these manipulations in the controller action and in before_save in the model besides the fact that in the model it would be performed on all writes and in the controller only on that action?

Comment: No, there's no difference other than where the logic lives and when it runs (as you note). I suppose the choice would depend on how intrinsic the behaviour is to the model versus a quirk of the user interface. FWIW, the case you outlined feels more like a short-cut during initial creation rather than something you'd want to enforce every time the model got changed.

Comment: Unfortunately I am using Devise for user management and can neither change the controller action without rewriting the entire controller nor changing the model without making registrations impossible due to devise's integrated email-check. Is there any way of using Javascript on the client-side to do these manipulations before submitting it to the server?